# iOS8 Custom Keyboard with XIB file does not scroll up the UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ios8, ios8-extension

I have a custom keyboard extension in my app that loads with a XIB file. The keyboard has several buttons and all of them are grouped into an array. When I tap into a text field on the web view, the custom keyboard appears from the bottom, but the web view does not scroll up, as it should do normally and the keyboard is overlapping the web view (The text field is still under the keyboard). But the default keyboard appears to work fine. Also there is a lag in the custom keyboard for the first time it appears. I am setting two user defined runtime values, one for the corner radius for each button on my keyboard and border width.
Does this have any effect on the lag in the appearance and also the scroll issue I am facing??? Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I checked it by removing the user defined runtime values for all the buttons, but still the problem persists.

Comment: What web page exactly?

Comment: Its the login page of my Client. The web page allows the user to enter the login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a custom keyboard developer. This problem is likely to be yet another bug of keyboard extension on iOS8.

As far as I know, custom keyboard on iOS8 itself has many bugs and performance issues - lag for first appearing, jumping between textfield when trying to add a contact in Contact.app, causing textfield disappear when trying to write a review in the App Store, to name just a few.

I'm thinking Apple is a little too intense to bring custom keyboard to iOS8 when it's not that stable. And there is nothing we can do but to wait for iOS 8.2 and following update.

Comment: I updated to iOS 8.1.3 but still the problem has not been resolved... :(